# find total incoming and outgoing time

Tags: calls, data-monitoring

I am using HTC WildFire, and what to find how long I have been talking on the phone since purchase?

i.e., I want to find out, my total incoming and outgoing call duration

Answer (score -1):

I found a free app that will track this information for you: [Call Meter NG](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.ub0r.de.android.callMeterNG).  I don't know if installing this app right now will give you historical data but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Nope, it didn't help me figure out historical data